# Why can you omit existential there when an adverbial phrase begins the sentence? Can you omit it in an existential question?

Tags: grammaticality, existential-constructions

> There are zebras in the zoo.

Becomes:

> In the zoo (there) are zebras.

Does "in the zoo" become the subject instead of "there"? If so, if we don't omit "there", does that mean "there" is the subject and "in the zoo" is an oblique complement?

Can you omit it in an existential question? Like this:

> Are (there) zebras in the zoo?

Comment: *Are zebras in the zoo?* is "syntactically valid", but idiomatically unlikely without "existential **there**" or some kind of "determiner" ("**the**" or "**any**", for example).

Comment: *In the zoo are zebras* is an example of inversion, and the subject is "zebras".

Comment: @StuartF yes, and even in the first sentence, "There are zebras in the zoo" zebras is still the subject. OP asks if "there" is the subject or if "In the zoo" is the subject.